# FluentValidation exception, abstractValidator cs not found

Tags: unit-testing, fluentvalidation

I am doing UnitTest,when ever debug the method it throws exception saying AbstractValidator.cs not found, ValidationTestExtension.cs not found and i re-install the FluentValidation, fluentValidation.mvc5 but couldn't resolve,..what should i do?

Comment: Are you using git by any change? and are you in a feature branch?

Answer (score 0):

Two things,

first make sure that in your controller where youre making the call for that model you have

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
```

If that doesnt fix it, go to your solution, right click > properties, in properties check the 'Debug Source Files' and add the files to the Do not look for these source files:' section.